# SAPUI5 sap.ui.table table issue in EDGE browser : First column with button occupies first rows and then other columns come in to below rows

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

sap.ui.table is used to create a table with columns. Columns have multiple controls and it has template.
Now in some systems on EDGE Browser, first column comes occupies entire row.
same happens for all visible rows on the screen. Remaining columns comes as a row together.

This is happening only on edge browser.

I tried changing width of all columns to "auto". It doesn't work.

Please help.

```
<mvc:View controllerName="s2s.delivery.create.controller.Worklist"
    xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:t="sap.ui.table" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:tnt="sap.tnt" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Page title="{i18n>panelTitle}">
        <core:Fragment fragmentName="s2s.delivery.create.Fragments.ToolHeaderBar"
            type="XML" />

<t:Table id="table1" rows="{openShipment>/}"
                    selectionMode="None" ariaLabelledBy="title"
                    enableCellFilter="true"
                    filter="filterOrder"
                    fixedColumnCount="1">
                    <t:toolbar>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <ToolbarSpacer />
                        <Button icon="sap-icon://refresh" text = "{i18n>refresh}" press="handleRefresh" type="Emphasized"/>
                    </Toolbar>
                </t:toolbar>
                    <t:columns>

                        <!-- <t:Column width="8rem" hAlign="Center"> -->
                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Button text="{i18n>Deliver}" type="Emphasized" press="handleDelivery"
                                    icon="sap-icon://shipping-status" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>

                        <t:Column width="auto" 
                                  filterProperty="OrderNo" 
                                  defaultFilterOperator="StartsWith" 
                                  sortProperty="OrderNo">

                            <Label width="6rem" text="{i18n>original}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>OrderNo}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>

                        <t:Column width="auto" >                                  
                            <Label width="6rem" text="{i18n>Item}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>ItemsNo}" />
                            </t:template> 
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="auto" sortProperty="GidateInt">

                            <Label width="6rem" text="{i18n>GIDate}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>GIDate}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>

                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>Status}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <core:Icon src="sap-icon://color-fill"
                                    color="{path:'openShipment>Status', formatter:'.setStatusColor'}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>

                        <t:Column width="auto" 
                                  filterProperty="Material" 
                                  defaultFilterOperator="StartsWith" 
                                  sortProperty="Material" >

                            <Label text="{i18n>Material}" />
                            <t:template>
                            <Text text="{openShipment>Material}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>

                        <t:Column width="16rem">
                            <Label text="{i18n>matDesc}" />
                            <t:template>
                            <Text text="{openShipment>MaterialDesc}"/>
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>

                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>OrdQty}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <ObjectNumber number="{path:'openShipment>OrderQty', formatter:'.displayDecimal'}" numberUnit="{openShipment>OrderQtyUnit}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="6rem" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>AvalQty}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <ObjectNumber number="{path:'openShipment>AvailQty', formatter:'.displayDecimal'} " numberUnit="{openShipment>AvailQtyUnit}" />

                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>ShipPoint}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>ShippingPoint}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>PrevWork}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>PrevWorkCenter}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="16rem" hAlign="Center" 
                                  filterProperty="CustomerName" 
                                  defaultFilterOperator="Contains" 
                                  sortProperty="CustomerName">

                            <Label text="{i18n>CustName}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>CustomerName}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>

                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>Country}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>Country}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>DocType}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>DocTypeDesc}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center"
                                  filterProperty="Zzaufnr" 
                                  defaultFilterOperator="StartsWith" 
                                  sortProperty="Zzaufnr">

                            <Label text="{i18n>ProdOrder}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>Zzaufnr}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>ProdStatus}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>Zzstat}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>packMaterial}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>PackingMaterial}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>packSpec}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>ZzpackagingSpec}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>
                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>cutCham}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>Zztext}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>



                        <t:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center">
                            <Label text="{i18n>Operation}" />
                            <t:template>
                                <Text text="{openShipment>Zzvornr} - {openShipment>Zzltxa1}" />
                            </t:template>
                        </t:Column>

                    </t:columns>
                </t:Table>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Comment: did you checked if this also happens with ui.table on ui5 samples site with edge browser? When I check it myself I dont see any issues. Also what I see is that you are using old deprecated things like t:toolbar. Then you use fixedColumnCount=1 and width=auto... not sure i auto does work with it - I dont think so. I would suggest to clean your code and delete some things out of your code like a try and error thing until everything looks good and you found out why it's happening

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that UI5 [plans to abandon classic Edge](https://ui5.sap.com/1.75.0/#/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933): _"The next stable SAPUI5 release that comes after SAPUI5 **1.71** will be the last SAPUI5 release to support Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML)"_. Since Microsoft themselves abandoned the classic Edge, I'd advocate for moving to the new Edge in your organization.